# How to add a '.Contains()' to the where clause of a query?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this query but I need to add a *where* clause that uses 'Contains()' so I can check the db for a list of accountIDs, the reason I need to do it this way is because I have to first check if there are any accountID's and if there are it must execute the 'Contains()' in the where clause but the compiler complains if I try do it this way but given what the method has to do I can't figure out another way to do it given the fact that there are so many tables joined in the query.

My code:

```
bool UseAcc = false;

if (accountIds != null && accountIds.Count > 0)
{
    UseAcc = true;
}

var query = (from i in db.Incidents
             join s in db.Sites on i.SiteID equals s.SiteID
             join a in db.Accounts on i.AccountID equals a.AccountID
             join st in db.Status on i.StatusID equals st.StatusID
             join currentUser in db.Users on i.CurrentAssignedUser equals currentUser.UserID
             join loggedByUser in db.Users on i.LoggedByUser equals loggedByUser.UserID
             join createdByUser in db.Users on i.CreatedByUser equals createdByUser.UserID
             join l in db.Locations on i.Location equals l.LocationID into locList
             from loc in locList.DefaultIfEmpty()
             join q in db.QuestionCategories on i.QuestionCategoryID equals q.QuestionCategoryID
             join ia in db.IncidentActions on i.IncidentID equals ia.IncidentID into iaList
             from actions in iaList.DefaultIfEmpty()

            //If 'UseAcc' gets set to true then execute the contains section of the or statement
             where (i.Active == true) &&
                   (UseAcc = false || a => accountIds.Contains(a.AccountID))

             select new
             {
                 Title = i.Title,
                 IncidentID = i.IncidentID,
                 StatusName = st.StatusName,
                 StatusID = i.StatusID,
                 ReferenceNumber = i.ReferenceNo,
                 AccountName = a.AccountName,
                 AccountID = i.AccountID,
                 SiteName = s.SiteName,
                 SiteID = i.SiteID,
                 LocationName = loc.LocationName,
                 LocationID = i.Location,
                 CatName = q.QuestionCategoryName,
                 CatID = i.QuestionCategoryID,
                 CurrentAssignedUser = currentUser.FirstName + " " + currentUser.LastName,
                 AssignedUserID = i.CurrentAssignedUser,
                 CreatedByUser = createdByUser.FirstName + " " + createdByUser.LastName,
                 DateCreated = i.LoggedDate,
                 DepartmentID = i.DepartmentID,
                 Logger = loggedByUser.FirstName + " " + loggedByUser.LastName,
                 LoggedBy = i.LoggedByUser,
                 EscalationCount = i.EscalationCount)
             });
```

I would paste the whole method but its really big.

I have looked at examples online but they can't work either because alot of them use an AsQueryable with a single table and this query has many tables joined.

Please Help.

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: Remove `a => ` from `a => accountIds.Contains(a.AccountID))` (you already have `a` range variable in scope).

Comment: No im not using Entity Framework

Comment: What is the compiler error message? Maybe you don't know the difference between `=` and `==`.

Comment: @Ivan Stoev - That worked, the only issue I have now is if the list is empty it does not return any data unless I specify and accountID in the list, do you know why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

```
var accounts = db.Accounts.AsQueryable();
if (accountIds != null && accountIds.Count > 0)
{
    accounts = accounts.Where(a => accountIds.Contains(a.AccountID));
}

var query = (from i in db.Incidents
             join s in db.Sites on i.SiteID equals s.SiteID
             join a in accounts on i.AccountID equals a.AccountID
             join st in db.Status on i.StatusID equals st.StatusID
             join currentUser in db.Users on i.CurrentAssignedUser equals currentUser.UserID
             join loggedByUser in db.Users on i.LoggedByUser equals loggedByUser.UserID
             join createdByUser in db.Users on i.CreatedByUser equals createdByUser.UserID
             join l in db.Locations on i.Location equals l.LocationID into locList
             from loc in locList.DefaultIfEmpty()
             join q in db.QuestionCategories on i.QuestionCategoryID equals q.QuestionCategoryID
             join ia in db.IncidentActions on i.IncidentID equals ia.IncidentID into iaList
             from actions in iaList.DefaultIfEmpty()


             select new
             {
                 Title = i.Title,
                 IncidentID = i.IncidentID,
                 StatusName = st.StatusName,
                 StatusID = i.StatusID,
                 ReferenceNumber = i.ReferenceNo,
                 AccountName = a.AccountName,
                 AccountID = i.AccountID,
                 SiteName = s.SiteName,
                 SiteID = i.SiteID,
                 LocationName = loc.LocationName,
                 LocationID = i.Location,
                 CatName = q.QuestionCategoryName,
                 CatID = i.QuestionCategoryID,
                 CurrentAssignedUser = currentUser.FirstName + " " + currentUser.LastName,
                 AssignedUserID = i.CurrentAssignedUser,
                 CreatedByUser = createdByUser.FirstName + " " + createdByUser.LastName,
                 DateCreated = i.LoggedDate,
                 DepartmentID = i.DepartmentID,
                 Logger = loggedByUser.FirstName + " " + loggedByUser.LastName,
                 LoggedBy = i.LoggedByUser,
                 EscalationCount = i.EscalationCount)
             });
```